# Filter ids from an object list

Tags: flutter

I need to filter ids from an object list and add those id list to a new array.Please suggest a way to do this.As per the below example I need to filter the ids from the '_studentDetails' list and store those ids in '_idList' array.

Example:

```
List<int> _idList = [];

List<Student> _studentDetails = [];

_studentDetails = [
       Student(id:1 , name:'Peter' , age: 14),
       Student(id:2 , name:'Anne' , age: 20),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`list.map()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) method
you loop through the list items and for every one you return the value of its preoperty `id` then convert all the returned values to list:

```dart
List<int> _idList = _studentDetails.map((student) => student.id).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks in advance! If I want to check this List<int> _idList = [];  with a hashmap. HashMap<int, bool> _checks = new HashMap(); which means if these ids contains int list in hashmap.how should I check it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the list of ids, you can use the method `.map`:

```dart
List<int> _idList = [];

List<Student> _studentDetails = [];

_studentDetails = [
       Student(id:1 , name:'Peter' , age: 14),
       Student(id:2 , name:'Anne' , age: 20),
];

_idList.addAll(
  _studentDetails.map((student) => student.id),
);
```

Comment: Thanks in advance! If I want to check this List<int> _idList = []; with a hashmap. HashMap<int, bool> _checks = new HashMap(); which means if these ids contains int list in hashmap.how should I check it ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, you have `HashMap<int, bool> _checks = new HashMap();` and you want to have `id: true` for every `id` in `_idList`. Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: If yes, you could do `_checks.addEntries(_idList.map((id) => MapEntry(id, true)));`

Comment: No I want to check if the hashmap contains the id list we have added to this array --> _idList.

{73: true, 74: true, 75: false, 76: false}
Hashmap contains data like this. 

And the List<int> _idList = [73,74];

I want to check if the hashmap has these ids

Comment: But where is the list of all the ids (`73`, `74`, `75` and `76` in this case)? If you have it you can do something like `_checks.addEntries(allIds.map((id) => MapEntry(id, _idList.contains(id))));` where `allIds` is the list of all the possible ids. In your example, `allIds = [73, 74, 75, 76]`

Comment: if I say clearly I have a checkbox list which I have map with this hashmap...because I want to save the id and the checkbox value.so when I tick them the hashmap will update. now I want to check the selected checkbox id check and inactive those checkboxes.i will be getting those ticked ids in a different array.thats why I wanted to filter those ids from the array and keep them in a separate list.now I want to check that list with the  hashmap and if the hashmap contains those ids.hope I have cleared everything :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using **forEach() loop**

Below the code:

```
void main(){
  List<int> _idList = [];

List<Student> _studentDetails = [];

_studentDetails = [
       Student(id:1 , name:'Peter' , age: 14),
       Student(id:2 , name:'Anne' , age: 20),
];
  
  _studentDetails.forEach((element) {
    _idList.add(element.id);
    
  } );
  
  print(_idList);
}

class Student{

  int id;
 String? name;
  int? age;
  
  Student({required this.id, required this.name, required this.age});
}
```